# match numbers if line starts with keyword

Tags: python, regex

I've got a file that looks like this:

```
foo: 11.00 12.00  bar 13.00
bar: 11.00 12.00 bar
foo: 11.00 12.00
```

and would like to extract all numbers in lines beginning with the keyword "foo:". Expected result:

```
['11.00', '12.00', '13.00']
['11.00', '12.00']
```

Now, this is easy, if I use two regexes, like this:

```
    if re.match('^foo:', line):
        re.findall('\d+\.\d+', line)
```

but I was wondering, if it is possible to combine these into a single regex?

Thanks for your help,
MD

Comment: You regex suggests that 'foo' should come at the beginning of the line, but you don't mention it in the description. Is it indeed the case?

Comment: Yes, that's case. I changed the description.

Comment: Short answer: No, you can't do both in the same regex if you don't know how many numbers there will be, at least not in Python. You could do it in .NET, though, where indefinite repetition in lookbehind assertions is supported: `(?<=^foo.*)\d+\.\d+` (with the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option).

Comment: What's your reason for wanting to combine them into a single regex? I find your current solution rather readable. One thing you change is to use `line.startswith("foo:")` instead of using `re.match` for the condition, the regex is not needed there.

Comment: @robinst You are right, it's working and readable, so there is no particular reason ... I was just curious whether it works otherwise.

Comment: @MikeD What Tim said +1.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker That sounds very plausbile. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly what you asked for, but since it's recommended to use standard Python tools instead of regexes where possible, I'd do something like this:

```
import re

with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    [re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', line) for line in f if line.startswith('foo')]
```

UPDATE

And this will return the numbers after 'foo' even if it's anywhere in the string rather than just in the beginning:

```
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    [re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', line.partition('foo')[2]) for line in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all lines in the file always have the same number of numbers, you can use the following regex:

```
"^foo:[^\d]*(\d*\.\d*)[^\d]*(\d*\.\d*)[^\d]*(\d*\.\d*)"
```

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "foo: 11.00 12.00 bar 13.00"
>>> re.match("^foo:[^\d]*(\d*\.\d*)[^\d]*(\d*\.\d*)[^\d]*(\d*\.\d*)", line).groups()
('11.00', '12.00', '13.00')
>>>
```

Using parentheses around a part of the regular expression makes it into a group that can be extracted from the match object. See the Python documentation for more information.

Comment: Thank you, but no, I'm afraid the number is variable, I'll modify the example to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do without the first regexp and instead filter lines in a list comprehension by comparing the first four characters of the line, and compile the inner regexp:

```
import re

with open("input.txt", "r") as inp:
    prog=re.compile("\d+\.\d+")
    results=[prog.findall(line) for line in inp if line[:4]=="foo:"]
```